# How can I add Select Distinct?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, distinct

This query search for products, there are products that has the same name but not the same size or whatever.

How can I add Select Distinct on this code?

```
private function query_products($category = 1, $id = NULL, $search = NULL){  
    $this->db->select('PP.*');  
    $query= $this->db->from("PLUGIN_PRODUCTS PP");  

    //->where('PCP.COUNTRY', $country);  


    if($search == NULL):  
    $query = $query->where('PP.PRODUCT_CATEGORY', $category);  

    else:

    $query = $query->like('PP.PRODUCT_NAME', $search)  
            ->or_like('PP.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION', $search)  
            ->or_like('PP.PRODUCT_CODE', $search)  
            ->group_by("PP.ID");
    endif;  

    if(!empty($id)):  
    $query = $query->where('PP.ID', $id);  
    endif;  

    return $query;  
  }
```

Comment: `->group_by("PP.PRODUCT_NAME");`

Comment: I already try chaging "->group_by("PP.PRODUCT_NAME");" but still not working

Comment: Already working, Thanks.

Comment: CAN I USE GROUP BY FOLLOW 2 DIFFERENT CONDITIONS?

Comment: are you trying to comment on echo_me's answer?

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
   ->group_by("PP.ID");
```

to

```
  ->group_by("PP.PRODUCT_NAME , PP.PRODUCT_SIZE");
```

Comment: you have to say what or what happen and why didnt work , look this edited answer

Comment: @user3537806 says "CAN I USE GROUP BY FOLLOW 2 DIFFERENT CONDITIONS? "

Comment: can I use grupo by folllow 2 different conditions?

Comment: like : "->group_by('PP.PRODUCT_NAME' , 'PRODUCT_SIZE');"